# Stopping services in multiple services using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to stop services on multiple servers using the below loop. The same loop works fine while starting the services.

I have done all the research to figure out why the below code reads only the first line of the text and ignores the rest.(meaning `serverlist_prod_ovo.txt` contains list of servers but the below code takes only the first server and ignores the rest) but when starting it goes through all the server

Script to stop:

```
$computers=gc "C:\scripts\ZFA PROD Scripts\ServerList_PROD_OVO.txt"

invoke-command -computer $computers -scriptblock{get-wmiobject -Class win32_service -Filter "name='OvCtrl'"} | foreach-object{
    if ($_.state -eq "Started")
        {Stop-Service -InputObject $(Get-Service -computer $computers -DisplayName 'OvCtrl');}
    else
        {write-host "'HP OpenView Ctrl Service' is already Stopped in "$_.PSComputerName  -ForegroundColor green}
    }
```

Please help me here to understand where I am wrong .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreach is not iterating the list of computers actually:

This should do your work:

```
$computers=gc "C:\scripts\ZFA PROD Scripts\ServerList_PROD_OVO.txt"

foreach($comp in $computers)
{
  If( (get-wmiobject -ComputerName $comp -Class win32_service -Filter "name='OvCtrl'").State -eq "Started")
    {
     Get-Service -ComputerName $comp -DisplayName 'OvCtrl' | Stop-Service -Force
    }
  else
    {
    write-host "'HP OpenView Ctrl Service' is already Stopped in "$_.PSComputerName  -ForegroundColor green
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Ranadip Dutta for the help.

Comment: Not a problem mate. Happy to help you out. @SriL